# How do I make an action at a specific time when the phone is locked?

Tags: android

I have this method. The problem is that it does not work when I lock the phone. It only shows me the notification if the phone has the screen on, if I block it and I activate it only 5 minutes later (it is 9:00 p.m. and I put it on at 9:05 p.m.), nothing happens. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803119/android-execute-action-when-phone-is-locked) questions, but I don't know how to start it at a specific time. Thanks in advance and please don't check this question as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803119/android-execute-action-when-phone-is-locked) question

```
public void startBroucast(int a,int b) {
      int minutes=a;
      int hours=b;
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.add(Calendar.HOUR,hours);
       c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);
       Timer time = new Timer();
       time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              showNotification();
           }
       },c.getTime());
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AlarmManager to schedule tasks in the future. Here's how you can do that:

```
public void startBroucast(int minutes,int hours) {

   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hours);
   c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);

long timeInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);

    mNotificationId = 123; //the id of the notification - you can use it to 
    //change the notification later

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),mNotificationId,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis,pendingNotificationIntent);
}
```

Now, you need to create the NotificationReceiver class.

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       createNotification(); //this is where you create and schedule your notification
    }
}
```

You also need to register the BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifext.xml

```
<receiver
        android:name=".util.NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```